# Spring Security BCrypt always look for “$2a” regex

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I am implementing `Spring Security` with `Spring Boot`. And I've generated password online using `BCrypt` generator. But when I try to login I got the error message:

> 2019-10-18 11:10:56.983  WARN 53908 --- [io-9090-exec-10]
> o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not
> look like BCrypt.

After some research, I found out that there is a bug in `Spring Security` where `BCrypt` only looks for `$2a` regex. Can anyone explain to me to solve these issues?

Comment: can you point us if it is a known bug in spring or you have just concluded it's a bug, as a matter of fact, for me all password encoded using BCryptPasswordEncoder password encoder starts with $2a so I see nothing wrong here

Comment: Not all BCrypt starts with $2a, There is a bunch of BCrypt online generator out there and i am 100% sure that not all start with $2a. Please do some researche before any comments.

Comment: I mentioned **for me** specifically in my comments, I used BCryptPasswordEncoder from spring and tried is dozen times, not a single time I have found it is without $2a. though as you suggested, I will further look into same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a default `Spring Boot` **2.1.x** supports `spring-security-core-5.1.x` which generally generate `BCrypt` of `$2a` version

This version doesn't support `BCryptPasswordEncoder` with different versions.

If you want to use other versions, you need to upgrade `spring-security-core` version

Add below in your pom.xml

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

then create your `BCryptPasswordEncoder` bean as below

```java
@Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
public BCryptPasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {

    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2B);
    return bCryptPasswordEncoder;

}
```

**you can pass your desired version in the constructor of BCryptPasswordEncoder.**

possible values are

> - BCryptVersion.$2A
> - BCryptVersion.$2Y
> - BCryptVersion.$2B

Comment: now spring boot 2.2 is out and it supports BCryptVersion