# Spring Security - Encoded Password Does Not Look Like BCrypt

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I can't login with the correct details as the program keeps stating that the encoded password does not look like bcrypt. Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm using JDBC authentication.

I have the correct database table as well, with enough space for the encoded password. I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

JSP FORM:
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="user"
action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/processLogin">

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <label for="inputUser">Username: </label> <input name="username"
                            type="text" path="username" id="inputUser" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Username" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword">Password: </label> 
                        <input name="username" type="password" path="password"
                            id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                            required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label> <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                            Remember Password
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                    
            </form:form>
```

Security Config:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource securityDataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/management/**").authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/processLogin").defaultSuccessUrl("/management/dashboard").permitAll();

    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

}

@Bean
@Autowired
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Login Controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

  @Autowired
  private UserServiceImpl userService;


  @GetMapping("/login")
  public String showLoginForm(Model model) {

    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "login";
  }

  @PostMapping("/processLogin")
  public String processLogin(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {

    if (userService.findUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()) != null) {
        return "/management/dashboard";
    } else {
        return "/access-denied";
    }
  }
}
```

My database [image: here]

Comment: If the problem was solved, please consider to accept the answer that helped.

Comment: Maybe consider looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447685/spring-security-bcrypt-always-look-for-2a-regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your database entries, it seems like you were using:

```
org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder
```

once and switched back to:

```
org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder
```

Only the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` is capable of handling passwords encoded with different schemes.

If you want to stick with your, currently configured, `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, you need to:

1. remove the prefix `{bcrypt}`
2. Encode the two passwords `test123` for `john` and `susan` with a `BCryptPasswordEncoder`

Answer (score 7):

I solved my issue by using `BcryptPasswordEncoder` as follow

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByuserName(userName);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("userName" + userName + "Not found in the database");
    }

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getName(), new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()), getGrantedAuth(user));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code to **securityconfig.java**
if you **dont want to use Bcryp**t at all
works like a charm

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
   return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).